# SAX XML in Android

Tags: android

This is my XML File where I need to get ID value based on its name .For Example I am displaying the **Home Page**,**My Results**,**My Attendance** ,**Home**,**Attendance** ,**Apply Leave**,**Apply Student Leave**,**Apply Short Leave**  in an Listview

But,

When I click on the **Home Page** I have to get the value as **2298**
    When I click on the **My Results** I have to get the value as **2431**
    When I click on the **My Attendance** I have to get the value as **2415**
    When I click on the **Home** I have to get the value as **20461**
    When I click on the **My Attendance** I have to get the value as **20613**  like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<MenusByRole>


  <MenuByRole InstanceID="519" RoleID="614">
    <MainMenu Id="2298">Home Page</MainMenu>
    <MainMenu Id="2431">My Results</MainMenu>
    <MainMenu Id="2415">My Attendance</MainMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="6121" MainMenuId="2298">FLASH NEWS</SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="6122" MainMenuId="2298">BEST PERFORMERS</SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="6123" MainMenuId="2298">GENERAL NOTICES</SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="6124" MainMenuId="2298">TIME TABLES And SCHEDULES</SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="6125" MainMenuId="2298"> COOL LINKS</SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="6126" MainMenuId="2298">TIP OF THE WEEK</SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="2416" MainMenuId="2415">Attendance Details</SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="2417" MainMenuId="2415">Summary</SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="14678" MainMenuId="2431">Previous Result</SubMenu>
  </MenuByRole>

 <MenuByRole InstanceID="604" RoleID="1184">
    <MainMenu Id="20461">Home</MainMenu>
    <MainMenu Id="20613">Attendance</MainMenu>
    <MainMenu Id="20933">Apply Leave</MainMenu>
    <MainMenu Id="22856">Apply Student Leave</MainMenu>
    <MainMenu Id="22855">Apply Short Leave</MainMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="20616" MainMenuId="20613" Url="/">Post Attendance</SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="6121" MainMenuId="20461" Url="/Notices.xaml">FLASH NEWS</SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="6122" MainMenuId="20461" Url="/Notices.xaml">BEST PERFORMERS</SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="6123" MainMenuId="20461" Url="/Notices.xaml">GENERAL NOTICES</SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="6131" MainMenuId="20461" Url="/Notices.xaml">TIME TABLES</SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="6125" MainMenuId="20461" Url="/Notices.xaml">COOL LINKS</SubMenu>
    <SubMenu Id="6137" MainMenuId="20461" Url="/Notices.xaml">THOUGHT OF THE DAY</SubMenu>    
  </MenuByRole>

</MenusByRole>
```

This is the code I have used for it...

```
public class MainMenu {
    private String id;
    private String Name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

}
```

*MainActivity.java Page*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static String id, instanceid, roleid, subid, s, iid, rid, userid;
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<MainMenu> munuIDList;
    MainMenu oMainMenu;
    boolean isReadData;
    String sName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {


                public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                        String qName, Attributes attributes)
                        throws SAXException {

                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("MenuByRole")) {
                        iid = attributes.getValue("InstanceID");
                        rid = attributes.getValue("RoleID");

                        munuIDList = new ArrayList<MainMenu>();
                        isReadData = false;
                    }
                    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("MainMenu")) {
                        id = attributes.getValue("Id");

                        isReadData = true;
                        oMainMenu = new MainMenu();
                        oMainMenu.setId(attributes.getValue("Id"));
                    }



                }

                public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                        String qName) throws SAXException {
                    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("MainMenu")) {

                            oMainMenu.setName(sName);
                            munuIDList.add(oMainMenu);
                            al.add(oMainMenu.getName());

                    }
                    sName = null;
                    isReadData = false;
                }

                public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
                        throws SAXException {

                    if (isReadData) {
                        sName = new String(ch, start, length);
                    }

                }
            };
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("menus.xml");
            saxParser.parse(is, handler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, al));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                SubMenu.alnew.clear();
                s = munuIDList.get(arg2).getId();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }



}
```

Here When I click on the **Home Page** it should show **2298** as Output in my Toast Message

But It is showing **20461** as the Output

I am unable to sole this problem. Please help me out regarding this Parsing .

Comment: I have checked your code but i think problr is at parsing you are setting your name but not id.So once check your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the intial of the ArrayList **munuIDList = new ArrayList();**

```
if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("MenuByRole")) {
                        iid = attributes.getValue("InstanceID");
                        rid = attributes.getValue("RoleID");

                        //munuIDList = new ArrayList<MainMenu>();
                        isReadData = false;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok try with this may this help you :

```
 DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {


            public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                    String qName, Attributes attributes)
                    throws SAXException {
                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("MenusByRole")) {

                    oMainMenu = new MainMenu();
                     munuIDList = new ArrayList<MainMenu>();

                }

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("MenuByRole")) {
                    iid = attributes.getValue("InstanceID");
                    rid = attributes.getValue("RoleID");

                    isReadData = false;
                }
                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("MainMenu")) {
                    id = attributes.getValue("Id");

                    isReadData = true;

                    oMainMenu.setId(attributes.getValue("Id"));
                }



            }

            public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                    String qName) throws SAXException {
                if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("MainMenu")) {

                        oMainMenu.setName(sName);
                        munuIDList.add(oMainMenu);
                        al.add(oMainMenu.getName());

                }
                sName = null;
                isReadData = false;
            }

            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
                    throws SAXException {

                if (isReadData) {
                    sName = new String(ch, start, length);
                }

            }
        };
```

Comment: But this is not correct because it is taken the last Id value for every listview item